# How to install skype in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, skype

I am new to android app development. I want to create an intent to launch Skype. In order to test this, I assume that the emulator must have Skype already installed.

I tried to launch the play store on the emulator to get the Skype App. But the Google Playstore, when launched on emulator it complains that there is no wifi or data connection.

How can I get the emulator to connect to the host wifi(Wifi which the laptop is connected to?)?
Is there a another way to get Skype app on emulator without playstore?

Thank you

Comment: Test it on your Android device. After all, you need to test your app on Android hardware at some point.

Comment: I am able to install Skype in an Android device and use it. Thanks!

Comment: What emulator, device and which system image are you using? The official emulator that comes with Android Studio bridges to the host's active network connection and it emulates the data connection in the AVD for the default system images provided by Studio/AVD Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the latest Android Studio and Emulator, you could get the Skype application APK file from other sites and drag it onto the emulator for it install the application.

However I do suggest as @CommonsWare stated, use a physical Android Device instead of an emulator as some (probably most) apps won't work correctly due to Google Play Services being missing. You could try the images in the Android SDK that contain part of the Google Play Services within them, it's worth a shot but not something to rely on for the long run.

Comment: That is a good idea. Will try to find the APK file and load into system-images of the emulator version I am using. Thanks!